# PHP get data from an array that was passed from a url

Tags: php, laravel

I'm passing an array through a callback url.

```
$pay = $this->pay->pay($request);
$details = http_build_query(array('data' => $pay['details']));

 $curl_post_data = [
            'CallBackURL' => 'https://98c94f211a3f.ngrok.io/api/confirmation/'. $details,
            'TransactionDesc' => $pay['narration'],
        ];
```

This callback url is then received by the follwing method. I then want to return to the original array passed and I'm currently doing it as follows:

```
    public function Confirmation($details, Request $request)
    {
        $data = $_GET[$details]['data'];
        var_dump($data);
    }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Undefined index: data[plot_id]=1&amp;data[house_id]=2&amp;data[rent_deadline][month_active]=June+2021&amp;data[rent_deadline][past_deadline]=0&amp;data[rent_deadline][days_to]=21&amp;data[rent_deadline][formatted_deadline_date]=Jun+24,+2021
```

How do I get the array back in it's original form?

Comment: Sending an associative array via GET request has no satifying solution as far as I know. Is there no way to do a POST request?

Comment: Do you need all that stuff in the url or would an identifier suffice that would enable you to fetch the data?

Comment: You could also not wrap the `$pay['details']` into an array but I don't know if that's what you want